# Xcode 12 Mac M1 with Cocoapods: I can build on simulator but not on device

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12, apple-m1

I have been searching a lot and most people seem to have the problem that they can run on the device but not on the simulator. Well for me its the other way around.

In order to get the cocoa pods to work using my new M1 Mac I added arm64 in excluded architectures. This works fine to run on the simulator. But when I try to run on a device I get the following error:

Red Error:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

(I get this error in the "project section")

Yellow warning:
None of the architectures in ARCHS (arm64) are valid. Consider setting ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) or updating it to include at least one value from VALID_ARCHS (arm64, arm64e, armv7, armv7s) which is not in EXCLUDED_ARCHS (arm64).

(I get this warning in the "project section" as well as in the "Pods section")

Anybody has any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: If you EXCLUDE arm64 then it seems obvious it's not running on on arm64 device.

Comment: Very true. But when I don't exclude it, the pods won't work. So either way I can't build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow my bad. My mistake was that I only removed "excluded architecture" from the project and I had to remove it from the pods also. Obviously. Whoops